# How to render multiple cards in from a data source that I fetched from an API, using Native Base?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to render a list of cards, each card contains data that I fetched from an API.

The problem is, if I use ListView from react-native component, it rendered just fine. But when I try to use Card from Native Base, I got errors. I think the problem come from how I put the Card and CardItem tags but I'm not sure how to fix it. Bellow is my code

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, ListView, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Card, CardItem, Body } from 'native-base';

export default class Movies extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('http://api.estudy.edu.vn/api/listitems')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson),
        }, function() {
          // do something with new state
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
        <Card>
          <CardItem>
            <Body>
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={(rowData) => 
              <Text>
              {rowData.id}, 
              {rowData.content}, 
              </Text>}
            </Body>
          </CardItem>
        </Card>
        <TextInput
            style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
            value={this.state.text}
        />
        <Button
         onPress={() => {
            fetch('http://api.estudy.edu.vn/api/listitems', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json', //accept kieu du lieu json server tra ve
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', // client gui du lieu kieu json len
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            content: this.state.text  // lay content o trong o text input       
            })
          })
            .then(
              fetch('http://api.estudy.edu.vn/api/listitems')
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                  let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
                  this.setState({
                  isLoading: false,
                  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson),
                  }, 
                  function() {
                        // do something with new state
                  });
                  })


              )
            .catch((error) => {console.error(error);})}}

         title="Learn More"
         color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to render your `<Card>` from a `<FlatList>`, see [FlatList official Doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) and replace `<MyListItem />` by your `<Card>`.